# Fetching line based on few characters python

Tags: python, fetch

I am writing a code to fetch lines based on keywords using python, the lines are basically from dns zone file.

For example

```
   norbert.google.com IN MX 10 mail1.google.com
   norbert.google.com IN MX 20 mail2.google.com
   borbert.google.com IN MX 30 mail4.google.co.in
```

If I fetch the lines based on MX string it essentially gives me all three entries. I want to fetch lines based on keyup kind of event. In short, as I start typing in it should give me back the whole line.

for Example if I type "bor" it should give me back third line.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
>>> s = '''norbert.google.com IN MX 10 mail1.google.com
...    norbert.google.com IN MX 20 mail2.google.com
...    borbert.google.com IN MX 30 mail4.google.co.in'''
>>> [line for line in s.splitlines() if 'bor' in line]
['   borbert.google.com IN MX 30 mail4.google.co.in']
```